# How to query increased column values in a table

Tags: ms-access

I've got this problem to find the **Regions where the electorates are growing most quickly** in the table below i.e. finding the largest average percentage of Regions growth rate in 2001, 2005 and 2010 or comparing each region's percentages in 2001, 2005 and 2010.

```
Region          Electorate  Constituency                ElectionYear
--------------  ----------  --------------------------  ------------
South East          109044  Isle of Wight                       2010
South East          107737  Isle of Wight                       2005
South East          106305  Isle of Wight                       2001
North West           90124  Manchester Central                  2010
London               89601  East Ham                            2010
London               88624  Croydon North                       2010
East Midlands        88378  Northampton South                   2005
London               88236  Brentford and Isleworth             2005
East Midlands        88058  Daventry                            2005
South East           88006  Banbury                             2005
East Midlands        86537  Daventry                            2001
South West           86324  Devizes                             2005
London               85943  Ilford South                        2010
London               85851  Kingston and Surbiton               2010
East Midlands        85450  Sleaford and North Hykeham          2010
East Midlands        85271  Northampton South                   2001
West Midlands        85241  Stratford-on-Avon                   2001
London               85078  West Ham                            2010
South West           84821  Bristol West                        2001
West Midlands        84540  Stratford-on-Avon                   2005
South East           84379  Banbury                             2010
London               84049  Brentford and Isleworth             2001
South East           83935  Winchester                          2005
London               83904  Harrow East                         2005
```

I tried to look at this by writing this code but I don't think I'm doing the right thing; I think there should be other ways better than this:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT Region, Electorate 
FROM DW_FastGrowingElectorateRegion 
WHERE Electorate = (SELECT MAX(Electorate) FROM DW_FastGrowingElectorateRegion) 
    OR Electorate = (SELECT MIN(Electorate) FROM DW_FastGrowingElectorateRegion ) 
GROUP BY Region, Electorate 
ORDER BY Electorate DESC;
```

The result is this:

```
Region           Electorate
South East       109044
Scotland         31909
```

Any help would be helpful and greatly appreciated as I've spent days trying to sort this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current query only selects the rows in your raw data that have the highest and lowest values for [Electorate]. You have a GROUP BY clause in your query, but you don't actually do any aggregation.

Start by creating a saved query in Access named [ElectorateSumsByRegionYear] as follows

```sql
SELECT 
    Region, 
    ElectionYear,
    Sum(Electorate) AS SumOfElectorate
FROM DW_FastGrowingElectorateRegion 
GROUP BY Region, ElectionYear
```

For the test data you provided, it returns

```
Region          ElectionYear  SumOfElectorate
--------------  ------------  ---------------
East Midlands           2001           171808
East Midlands           2005           176436
East Midlands           2010            85450
London                  2001            84049
London                  2005           172140
London                  2010           435097
North West              2010            90124
South East              2001           106305
South East              2005           279678
South East              2010           193423
South West              2001            84821
South West              2005            86324
West Midlands           2001            85241
West Midlands           2005            84540
```

Now we can create a saved query in Access named [ElectorateSumsCurrentPrevious] to return the results along with the corresponding results from the prior period

```sql
SELECT 
    CurrYear.Region, 
    ElectCurrPrevYr.ElectionYear AS CurrYear, 
    CurrYear.SumOfElectorate AS CurrSum, 
    ElectCurrPrevYr.PrevYear, 
    PrevYear.SumOfElectorate AS PrevSum
FROM 
    (
        ElectorateSumsByRegionYear AS CurrYear 
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT t1.Region, t1.ElectionYear, Max(t2.ElectionYear) AS PrevYear
            FROM 
                ElectorateSumsByRegionYear AS t1
                INNER JOIN
                ElectorateSumsByRegionYear AS t2
                    ON t1.Region = t2.Region
                        AND t1.ElectionYear > t2.ElectionYear
            GROUP BY t1.Region, t1.ElectionYear
        ) AS ElectCurrPrevYr 
            ON (CurrYear.ElectionYear = ElectCurrPrevYr.ElectionYear) 
                AND (CurrYear.Region = ElectCurrPrevYr.Region)
    ) 
    INNER JOIN 
    ElectorateSumsByRegionYear AS PrevYear 
        ON (ElectCurrPrevYr.PrevYear = PrevYear.ElectionYear) 
            AND (ElectCurrPrevYr.Region = PrevYear.Region);
```

returning

```
Region          CurrYear  CurrSum  PrevYear  PrevSum
--------------  --------  -------  --------  -------
East Midlands       2005   176436      2001   171808
East Midlands       2010    85450      2005   176436
London              2005   172140      2001    84049
London              2010   435097      2005   172140
South East          2005   279678      2001   106305
South East          2010   193423      2005   279678
South West          2005    86324      2001    84821
West Midlands       2005    84540      2001    85241
```

We can use that query as a basis for whatever "growth" measure we want to use, e.g.

```sql
SELECT 
    Region, 
    CurrYear, 
    CurrSum, 
    PrevYear, 
    PrevSum, 
    [CurrSum]-[PrevSum] AS Increase, 
    (CDbl([CurrSum])/CDbl([PrevSum]))^(1/([CurrYear]-[PrevYear]))-1 AS AvgAnnualGrowthRate
FROM ElectorateSumsCurrentPrevious;
```

which returns

```
Region          CurrYear  CurrSum  PrevYear  PrevSum  Increase  AvgAnnualGrowthRate  
--------------  --------  -------  --------  -------  --------  ---------------------
East Midlands       2005   176436      2001   171808      4628   6.66728558280982E-03
East Midlands       2010    85450      2005   176436    -90986     -0.134982342500498
London              2005   172140      2001    84049     88091       0.19629231270215
London              2010   435097      2005   172140    262957       0.20376263338977
South East          2005   279678      2001   106305    173373      0.273579774134796
South East          2010   193423      2005   279678    -86255  -7.10978631581222E-02
South West          2005    86324      2001    84821      1503   4.40078147996426E-03
West Midlands       2005    84540      2001    85241      -701  -2.06230641894412E-03
```

**Edit re: comment**

If you want a query that returns just the highest and lowest growth rates, then save the above query as [ElectorateGrowthByRegionYear] and then use something like

```sql
    SELECT TOP 1 * FROM ElectorateGrowthByRegionYear
    ORDER BY AvgAnnualGrowthRate DESC
UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP 1 * FROM ElectorateGrowthByRegionYear
    ORDER BY AvgAnnualGrowthRate ASC
```

Comment: You've done well but I think finding the largest average percentage of Regions growth rate in 2001, 2005 and 2010 or comparing each region's percentages in 2001, 2005 and 2010 would be just fine. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for your help. It has really given me an insight on using this code to solve different problems. If I may ask, can both largest and minimum average Region's percentage be determined using this code or has this code done the job?

Comment: Hi, Seasons greetings! If you don't mind I'll like to ask you another question.

Comment: @user3036566 If you have another question please post it via the link [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: I've asked the question on this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20808791/exempting-a-row-from-a-group-of-items-by-min-function-group-by-a-field)

Comment: Hi Gord, how can run all these query at a go? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user3036566 You just create the saved queries in Access and then run the final query when you want to retrieve the results. The saved queries are like subroutines in a program; they get called by the main program (the final query that returns the desired results) but they don't get "run" directly themselves.