# Exempting a row from a group of items by MIN function group by a field

Tags: ms-access

I'll like the output to populate the minimum score for each student in each class and year and group by class. My query looks like this but it's returning all records for me. Meanwhile, I only want the the records where score is minimum in a class.

SELECT Year, Student, Class, MIN(Score) FROM MyTable;

Thanks!

---

## |   Year    |Student| Class | Score |

|   2001    |   Con |   1   |   30  |

|   2001    |   Lab |   1   |   50  |

|   2001    |   Lib |   1   |   10  |

|   2001    |   Ind |   1   |   5   |

|   2001    |   Con |   2   |   40  |

|   2001    |   Lab |   2   |   35  |

|   2001    |   Lib |   2   |   50  |

|   2001    |   Ind |   2   |   80  |

|   2005    |   Con |   1   |   10  |

|   2005    |   Lab |   1   |   20  |

|   2005    |   Lib |   1   |   15  |

|   2005    |   Ind |   1   |   30  |

|   2005    |   Con |   2   |   50  |

|   2005    |   Lab |   2   |   40  |

|   2005    |   Lib |   2   |   15  |

|   2005    |   Ind |   2   |   35  |

|   2010    |   Con |   1   |   60  |

|   2010    |   Lab |   1   |   40  |

|   2010    |   Lib |   1   |   50  |

|   2010    |   Ind |   1   |   70  |

|   2010    |   Con |   2   |   10  |

|   2010    |   Lab |   2   |   20  |

|   2010    |   Lib |   2   |   15  |

|   2010    |   Ind |   2   |   30  |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this may work:

SELECT T1.*
FROM MyTable AS T1
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
(
SELECT Class, MIN(Score) AS MinScore
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Class
) AS T2
ON T1.Class = T2.Class
AND T1.Score = T2.MinScore

Comment: Hi, it works but what if i want to exclude some student from the result; say, student named 'Con' and Lab?